# How can i create/add scroll bars to UserControl?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a UserControl i dragged it over to form1 designer and i display text inside.

But there is a lot of text and there is no Scroll Bar property. I can set Auto scroll to true but it dosen't add any scroll bars.

The UserControl designer is empty there is no any control/s in the UserControl designer it's using DrawPath.

This is the UserControl code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;

namespace ScrollLabelTest
{
    public partial class Scroller : UserControl
    {
        Color[] _colors;
        /// <summary>
        /// String list.
        /// </summary>
        string[] m_text = new string[0];

        /// <summary>
        /// Offset for animation.
        /// </summary>
        int m_scrollingOffset = 0;

        /// <summary>
        /// Top part size of text in percents.
        /// </summary>
        int m_topPartSizePercent = 50;

        /// <summary>
        /// Font, which is used to draw.
        /// </summary>
        Font m_font = new Font("Arial", 20, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor
        /// </summary>
        public Scroller()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Enables double buffering (to remove flickering) and enables user paint.
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);

        }

        public void ScrollerColors(Color[] colors)
        {
            _colors = colors;
        }

        public Color[] ColorLines
        {
            get
            {
                return this._colors;
            }
            set
            {
                this._colors = value;
            }
        }



        /// <summary>
        /// Text to scroll.
        /// </summary>
        public string TextToScroll
        {
            get 
            {
                return string.Join("\n", m_text);
            }
            set 
            {
                string buffer = value;

                // Splits text by "\n" symbol.
                m_text = buffer.Split(new char[1] { '\n' });
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Timer interval.
        /// </summary>
        public int Interval
        {
            get
            {
                return m_timer.Interval;
            }
            set
            {
                m_timer.Interval = value;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Font, which is used to draw.
        /// </summary>
        public Font TextFont
        {
            get
            {
                return m_font;
            }

            set
            {
                m_font = value;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Top part size of text in percents (of control width).
        /// </summary>
        public int TopPartSizePercent
        {
            get
            {
                return m_topPartSizePercent;
            }
            set
            {
                if ((value >= 10) && (value <= 100))
                {
                    m_topPartSizePercent = value;
                }
                else
                    throw new InvalidEnumArgumentException("The value must be more than zero. and less than 100.");
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Paint handler.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void OnPaint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            // Sets antialiasing mode for better quality.
            e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

            // Prepares background.
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(this.BackColor), this.ClientRectangle);

            // Creates GraphicsPath for text.
            GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();

            // Visible lines counter;
            int visibleLines = 0;
           // Random r = new Random(); 

            Font drawFonts1 = new Font("Arial", 20, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

            //m_text = new[] { "foo", "42", "", "bar", "48", "", "boo", "13", "" };
            for (int i = m_text.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {

                Point pt = new Point((int)((this.ClientSize.Width - e.Graphics.MeasureString(m_text[i], m_font).Width) / 2),
                    (int)(m_scrollingOffset + this.ClientSize.Height - (m_text.Length - i) * m_font.Size));

                // Adds visible lines to path.
                if ((pt.Y + this.Font.Size > 0) && (pt.Y < this.Height))
                {
                    path.AddString(m_text[i], m_font.FontFamily, (int)m_font.Style, m_font.Size,
                        pt, StringFormat.GenericTypographic);

                    visibleLines++;
                }
            }

            // For repeat scrolling.
            if ((visibleLines == 0) && (m_scrollingOffset < 0))
            {
                m_scrollingOffset = (int)this.Font.SizeInPoints * m_text.Length;
            }



            int topSizeWidth = (int)(this.Width * m_topPartSizePercent / 100.0f);

            // Wraps Graphics path from rectangle to trapeze.
            path.Warp(
                new PointF[4] 
                { 
                    new PointF((this.Width - topSizeWidth) / 2, 0),
                    new PointF(this.Width - (this.Width - topSizeWidth) / 2, 0),
                    new PointF(0, this.Height),
                    new PointF(this.Width, this.Height)
                },
                new RectangleF(this.ClientRectangle.X, this.ClientRectangle.Y, this.ClientRectangle.Width, this.ClientRectangle.Height),
                null,
                WarpMode.Perspective
                );

            // Draws wrapped path.
            e.Graphics.FillPath(new SolidBrush(this.ForeColor), path);
            path.Dispose();

            // Draws fog effect with help of gradient brush with alpha colors.
            /*using (Brush br = new LinearGradientBrush(new Point(0, 0), new Point(0, this.Height),
                Color.FromArgb(255, this.BackColor), Color.FromArgb(0, this.BackColor)))
            {
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(br, this.ClientRectangle);
            }*/
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Starts the animation from the beginning.
        /// </summary>
        /// 
        public void Start()
        {
            // Calculates scrolling offset.
            m_scrollingOffset = (int)this.Font.SizeInPoints * m_text.Length;
            m_timer.Start();
        }

        public void Pause()
        {
            m_timer.Enabled = !m_timer.Enabled;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Stops the animation.
        /// </summary>
        public void Stop()
        {
            m_timer.Stop();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Timer handler.
        /// </summary>
        private void OnTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Changes the offset.
            m_scrollingOffset--;

            // Repaints whole control area.
            Invalidate();
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to set the [AutoScrollMinSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol.autoscrollminsize%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property. The AutoScrollMinSize property is used to manage the screen size allocated to the automatic scroll bars

syntax

```
public Size AutoScrollMinSize { get; set; }
```

Comment: there is an article about how to customise the autoscroll property on codeproject http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6914/Customize-a-panel-with-Autoscroll-property